# Handling error codes for in app billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am trying to implement in app billing in an android application. I have read the documentation and I have finished implementing in app billing except the part that handles the error codes. The documentation states the following

"Server Response Codes
The following table lists all of the server response codes that are sent from Google Play to your application. Google Play sends the response code synchronously as an integer mapped to the RESPONSE_CODE key in the response Bundle. Your application must handle all of these response codes.

Table 1. Summary of response codes for In-app Billing API calls."

[image]

So I have to handle all those error code. I have searched for an example on how to do it but I haven't found one.

Can anyone provide an example of handling ALL the error codes so I can follow it?

This is the method that receives the response error codes (that might be one of the errors in the above table)

```
 public void onError(int response, Exception e) {
        // handle errors here
        Log.w(LOG," in onError"+ "response is" + response);
    }
```

So as long as I understand from google documentation here I have to handle all the above error codes.

So I want to see an example. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: can you please show your current code?

Comment: show your code plzz

Comment: Basically I might receive one of the error codes in "onError" method. The google documentation states that I have to handle all the error codes. Now that I have a method that receives the error codes an example of handling the error depending on the code would be very  helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Because google says you have to handle all error does not mean you have to.

Its simply preference. I have created over 20 apps with full working billing functionality and i handle the errors the same way. the most important to me is always the `BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK`. The rest i just use else to group them together (because my users have no need for the specific error).

here is how i do mine:

```
@Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    //do my response is OK code here
                    return;
                }
                //do my response is an ERROR code here
            }
```

But in your case you can easily do this, if you want to handle all errors

```
                           @Override
                            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                                    //do my response is OK code here
                                    return;
                                } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() ==
    BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
        //do user cancelled here
        } 

            else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
            //do user cancelled here
            } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE) {
            //do SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE here
            } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.BILLING_UNAVAILABLE) {
            //do BILLING_UNAVAILABLE here
        }}
```

And so on and so forth.

PS. Doing the above will be faster and optimized using switch cases.